# magento setup:upgrade - JavaScript files broken

Tags: magento2.4

When I run the following commends, theme JavaScript file broken

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

Broken files (net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)):

```
/pub/static/version1697560192/frontend/Smartwave/porto/en_US/js/jquery.sticky.min.js
/pub/static/version1697560192/frontend/Smartwave/porto/en_US/js/jquery.lazyload.js 
pub/static/version1697560192/frontend/Smartwave/porto/en_US/StripeIntegration_Payments/js/stripe_payments_express.js
```

Notes:

Magento ver. 2.4.1

Application mode is default.

Answer (score 0):

If its your local development env, try changing the application mode to developer:

```bash
bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
```

If it is a production server, you need to deploy static files during the release:

```bash
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Comment: I run this "bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy" , but there was an error "Manual static content deployment is not required in "default" and "developer" modes.  In "default" and "developer" modes static contents are being deployed automatically on demand."

Comment: then I used this "bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f", but still same issue, the JavaScript broken

Comment: Can you check if those files actually exist?

Comment: yes, there are exist, and they in someway deleted when I run "php bin/magento setup:upgrade"

https://littlestars.ae/pub/static/version1697560192/frontend/Smartwave/porto/en_US/js/jquery.sticky.min.js

Comment: Try to run `bin/magento setup:upgrade` with --keep-generated, i.e. `bin/magento setup:upgrade --keep-generated`

Comment: I used "--keep-generated", it solved his issue, but new plugin has different issues using this one.

Comment: Whats the new issue?

Comment: After run "bin/magento setup:upgrade --keep-generated", I have the following error:

SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'tbpvuzrksv.stripe_webhooks' doesn't exist, query was: SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `stripe_webhooks` AS `main_table` WHERE (`config_version` = 12)

Comment: and new extinction JavaScript is missing: /pub/static/version1644520963/frontend/Smartwave/porto/en_US/stripejs.js